# Javascript:Inconsistency with arithmetic operators?

Tags: javascript

Background: In Finland the conventional grading system in schools is based on numbers and minus/plus signs. If a student gets 6+, that equals to 6.25, and 6- is equal to 5.75.

I have the following code:

```js
function miinustin() {
  var vanha = $('#summa').val();
  var valiUusi = vanha.slice(0, -1);
  var vikamerkki = vanha.slice(-1);
  if (vikamerkki === "-") {
    var uusi = valiUusi - 0.25;
    $('#summa').val(uusi);
  } else if (vikamerkki === "+") {
    var uusi = valiUusi + 0.25;
    $('#summa').val(uusi);
  } else if (vikamerkki === "½") {
    var uusi = valiUusi + 0.5;
    $('#summa').val(uusi);
  }
};

$('#summa').on("input", miinustin);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="" id="summa">
```

Why does `6-` become `5.75` but `6+` becomes `60.25` and `6½` becomes `60.50`, and how do I overcome this problem? I do realise that for some reason in the `else if` statements `0.25` and `0.50` are not considered numeric values, but why?

Comment: If you want good help it would be nice to translate de variable names to english so everyone can understand what they mean :)

Comment: for addition, you need to cast the string (input) to number. an easy way is to prepend a plus sign.

Comment: You are adding strings and numbers. "6" + 0.25 is "60.25" because 0.25 is coerced to "0.25".

Comment: Tip: `+` is not always an arithmetic operator in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one of the operands is a string, then the result of the expression with a plus oparator is a string.

For addition, you need to cast the string (input) to number. An easy way is to prepend a plus sign as [unary plus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus) to get a number for all operations.

```
var valiUusi = +vanha.slice(0, -1);
//             ^ unary +
```

```js
function miinustin() {
  var vanha = $('#summa').val();
  var valiUusi = +vanha.slice(0, -1);
  var vikamerkki = vanha.slice(-1);
  if (vikamerkki === "-") {
    var uusi = valiUusi - 0.25;
    $('#summa').val(uusi);
  } else if (vikamerkki === "+") {
    var uusi = valiUusi + 0.25;
    $('#summa').val(uusi);
  } else if (vikamerkki === "½") {
    var uusi = valiUusi + 0.5;
    $('#summa').val(uusi);
  }
};

$('#summa').on("input", miinustin);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="" id="summa">
```

Comment: For some reason, this stops the script from working altogether?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the values `valiUusi` and `vikamerkki` are both strings, which means that JavaScript will try to concatenate `0.25` or `0.5` instead of add or subtract them.

The solution is to convert those values into numbers before you use them, using [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

```js
function miinustin() {
  var vanha = $('#summa').val();
  var valiUusi = parseInt(vanha.slice(0, -1), 10);
  var vikamerkki = vanha.slice(-1);

  if (vikamerkki === "-") {
    var uusi = valiUusi - 0.25;
    $('#summa').val(uusi);
  } else if (vikamerkki === "+") {
    var uusi = valiUusi + 0.25;
    $('#summa').val(uusi);
  } else if (vikamerkki === "½") {
    var uusi = valiUusi + 0.5;
    $('#summa').val(uusi);
  }
};

$('#summa').on("input", miinustin);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="" id="summa">
```

Comment: This works for one runthrough, but if I decide to press (for example) `-` again, things go awry.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is Dynamically Typed Language.

```
var vanha = $('#summa').val(); // Is a String 
var valiUusi = vanha.slice(0, -1); // Is a String
```

Data types are converted automatically as needed during script execution

```
When you do  var uusi = valiUusi + 0.25; //
```

valiUusi is taken as a String - `In expressions involving numeric and string values with the + operator, JavaScript converts numeric values to strings`

Hence the value becomes **60.25**

However In statements involving **other** than "+" operators, JavaScript does not convert numeric values to strings

Hence var uusi = valiUusi + 0.25; becomes 5.75

```
The correct way to approach is to use : parseInt or parseFloat()
```

For further reading : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for pointing out the reason my code didn't work!

I found out (after knowing what to google for) that this works as well:

```
var valiUusi = vanha.slice(0, -1); 
valiUusi = Number(valiUusi);
```

Now the script works as intended: **every** time `-` is pressed, `0.25` is deducted from the value in the textfield. `+` and `½` work as well.